# Pause for loop until key is pressed

Tags: bash, for-loop

How can I run a for loop which pauses after each iteration until a key is pressed?
for example, if I wanted to print the line number of file1, file2, file3, but only continuing each after pressing a key:

```
for f in dir/file? ; do wc -l $f ; pause until key is pressed ; done
```

Apologies if this is trivial, I'm new to the coding.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `read` command to wait for a single character(`-n1`) input from the user

```
read -p "Press key to continue.. " -n1 -s
```

The options used from the `man read` page,

```
-n nchars return after reading NCHARS characters rather than waiting 
          for a newline, but honor a delimiter if fewer than NCHARS
          characters are read before the delimiter

-s      do not echo input coming from a terminal

-p      prompt output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before
        attempting to read
```

Answer (score 0):

@Stewart: Try:

```
cat script.ksh
trap "echo exiting...; exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
for file in /tmp/*
do
        wc -l $file
echo "Waiting for key hit.."
read var
        if [[ -n $var ]]
        then
                continue
        fi
done
```

This script will be keep on running until/unless system get a signal to kill it (eg--> cntl+c etc). Let me know if this helps. Logic is simple created a trap first line of script to handle user's interruptions, then created a for loop which will look into a directory with all the files(you could change it accordingly to your need too). then wc -l of the current file as per yours post shown. Then ask user to enter a choice if user enters anything then it will go to loop again and again.

Comment: This is the only answer I've found that is POSIX. Testing shortly.

Comment: @zaTricky, sure, please let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Works 100% - only down side is you *have* to press enter. All other "solutions" I've found use non-POSIX flags (such as -p, -s, -n)